# I can't read an XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

It's my first time working with XML files, yet I have a problem with a code as simple as:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('some_xml_file.xml')
s = ET.tostring(tree, method = 'xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

all I am trying to do here is reading the XML file as a string,
but whenever I try to run this I get an  error:

> AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'

I have no idea what I did wrong just yet, so I would need any hint
and thanks in advance

Comment: No, that's not "all you're doing there" – you're also attempting to serialize the tree using `ET.tostring`. Get rid of the `s = ...` line since you're not using it.

Comment: Also, you're not showing the traceback to your error, so we'd have to guess why it's happening.

Comment: s = ET.tostring(tree, encoding='unicode', method = 'xml')
  File "C:\Users\alaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1109, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding,
  File "C:\Users\alaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 748, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
  File "C:\Users\alaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 873, in _serialize_xml
    tag = elem.tag
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'

Comment: and I will be using `s` later on ..... as I  said I am trying to read the file in string format

Comment: If you want to read an XML file as a string, you don't need ElementTree, you just read the file. There's nothing XML-specific you can do with the string you get out of `ET.string`.

Comment: so U mean `tree = ET.string(file_name)` going to do the job here?

Comment: I meant `ET.tostring`, sorry. But no, I don't know what "the job" is for you; all your code does now is take an XML file, parse it, and spit out the parsed data back as XML.

Comment: I misunderstood U earlier, but I need later to do some text replacement on the file so there's no need to do any XML-specific operations

Comment: If you need to do text replacement, you don't need `xml.etree` at all, you just read the file as text, replace things, and write it back.

Comment: OMG!!! not because it's XML I will need to get into this headache!
the irony is that I just assumed so and started working with etree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ET.tostring` on the full tree; you can use it on the root element.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('some_xml_file.xml')
s = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), method='xml')
```

Comment: that was the problem..... I didn't notice it was applied to the root in the docs...... thanks for help